# How do I get the social media usernames using request queries?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to receive the social media from [this](https://foundation.app/@Pondering) profile using python's request library but I can't seem to make it work
Here is one of my attempts:

```
import requests
def get_user():
    url = "https://hasura2.foundation.app/v1/graphql"

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    query = """
        query hasuraUserProfileByPublicKey($publicKey: String!) {
            user: user_by_pk(publicKey: $publicKey) {
        ...HasuraUserFragment
        }
    }

    fragment HasuraUserFragment on user {
        instaSocialVerifs {
                0 {
                    username
                }
        }
        twitSocialVerifs {
                0 {
                    username
                }
        }
        links
    }
"""

payload = {
    "operationName": "hasuraUserProfileByPublicKey",
    "query": query,
    "variables": {
        "publicKey": "0xF9D6fcE6Cce28c0Cd62c5CAf045f4F6233888989"
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
response.raise_for_status()

return response.json()["data"]["user"]
```

I'm getting the error:

```
    return response.json()["data"]["user"]
    KeyError: 'data'
```

I'm fairly new to web scraping and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the error and how you should deal with dictionaries in future
When you use `response.json()["data"]["user]` if the response.json does not have data key you will get this error. My suggestion is first have a look at the `response.json()` print this one and see what kind of data it returns then I would suggest you to use a notation like this`response.json().get("data", {}).get("user","")` this wont give and error even if you dont get those keys in the response.